# why does my domain name immediately switch to showing its ip address once page loads?

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache2

I just registered a new domain name and set it to point to an AWS EC2 instance. When I enter the domain name, it loads fine, but then as soon as the page loads, the browser address text is updated to show the ip address (replaces the domain name). I cloned this EC2 from another server where this was not happening and where I hadn't done any non-default Apache2 server settings other than URL shortening to remove .html and .php file extensions. Any ideas what could be happening here? I tried it on multiple computers and multiple browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I had mistakenly updated the DNS record for forwarding rather than for the @ tag, so it was forwarding to the site.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your webserver is issuing a redirect after the first connection is made, and the redirect is pointed to the IP adress of the server. You can get more information to confirm this by using Chrome Network Console.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but it turned out to be my DNS record settings.